# Typescript: How do I define interfaces for nested (nested) objects?

Tags: json, typescript, types, nested

See below my current JSON payload:

```
{
  "state_1": {
    "date": [
     {
          1000: {
            "size": 3,
            "count": 0
          }
        }
      {
          1001: {
            "size": 3,
            "count": 1

          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

How would I set up the definition of the Example interface to model a type `state` that has a `date` which has a list of `id` (here `1000` and `1001`) which are a dictionary holding strings `size` and `count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index signature to handle unknown key definitions.

```
interface State {
    date: {
        [id: number]: {
            size: string;
            count: string;
        }
    }[];
}
```